# Android wordpress automatic fcm notification unable to receive

Tags: android, wordpress, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developed app for my Wordpress site and i integrated push notifications in it using FCM, when i send notification manually from firebase console, notification is received successfully but i don't know how to connect it with wordpress so that when new post is published, then notification is automatically sent.
Thanks in advance.
I am begginer

Answer (score 0):

You can install this WordPress plugin to get the work done

https://github.com/dream-space/wp-fcm/

It's very easy to configure this plugin!